# PHP intval() returns 0

Tags: javascript, php, string, integer

This might seem trivial, but the `intval()` is returning 0 in the following case:

```
$window_width = "<script type='text/javascript'>document.write(window.innerWidth);</script>";
$window_width2 = intval($window_width);
echo $window_width2;
```

`$window_width` will be `"1366"`.

`$window_width2` will be `0`.

I need `$window_width2` to be `integer`, not `string`.

Comment: `intval — Get the integer value of a variable`, please check here > http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php
and your `$window_width ` does not contain the integer value

Comment: You'll also find that you are mixing client side scripting with sever side execution.  For example the `window.innerWidth` will be available after the page is rendered, after which point php has already been finished for sometime.  Thus that value will not be available to it, baring something like ajax, and a database which is less then ideal.

Comment: intval returns integer value. it does not convert string to integer

Comment: @OwaisArain - your mistaken it will convert a string to an integer such as `intval('1')` will indeed become `1` however `<script></script>` is not a number and with then become `0`

Comment: I think I've got the hang of it. Many thanks!

Comment: you can also do `(int)$var` just to confuse you a bit more :-p, its called casting.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix thanks :p

Comment: `var_dump($window_width2);` its integer not string

Comment: @OwaisArain - and 0 is guess what an integer... Indeed.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer

Comment: @devpro Yes it is integer, but its value is 0...

Comment: just because of javascript value, `$window_width = (int)'100';` this should be int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$window_width` is holding a `string`(not `window.innerWidth`) which can not be converted to `string` hence **`0`** is returned!

`PHP` is executed on `sever`(Way Before `JavaScript` is executed) so it is impossible to access `window.innerWidth` over `PHP`, use `AJAX` to emit that data over `PHP`.

> [*The integer value of var on success, or 0 on failure.*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php#refsect1-function.intval-returnvalues)

*Strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the leftmost characters of the string. The common rules of [integer casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) apply.*

Answer (score 0):

`$window_width` can not be 1366, because you are mixing PHP and Javascript.

PHP is executed on Server side while JS is on User side. This means you can not just use values from JS in PHP.

Comment: It is 1366 for me.